# How to do arithmetic operation on last n rows from different tables in postgresql without join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a two tables (for examle table a with columns c, d and table b with column e). I'm trying to do math operation like this: (c + d) * e for every row in last **n** rows from this tables (`ORDER BY id desc limit n`) keeping the order of the lines.

I already tried this query:

```
SELECT f1.r1 * f2.r2 
FROM (
  select c + d as r1 
  from a 
  order by id desc 
  limit n
) as f1,
  (select e as r2 
   from b 
   order by id desc 
   limit n) as f2
```

but it returns n^2 columns (i just need n).

P.S: i can't use join beacuse id of rows in this tables are not correlate

Comment: Sample data and desired results in your question would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` not on `id` but on `row_number()`:

```
with u as 
(select c, d, row_number() over(order by id desc) as rownum_a from a),
v as (select e, row_number() over(order by id desc) as rownum_b from b)
(select c, d, e, (c + d)*e as "(c+d)*e" from u inner join v on rownum_a = 
rownum_b limit n)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f1e1f9a36a13769f6d0577824ecb7a66)